# Tortoise SVN - nothing happens when clicking content menu commands

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have `Tortoise SVN 1.6.15` installed on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.  It was working fine until yesterday.  There are the two problems that I see:

1. When I right-click to open the context menu and click on SVN command (Checkout, Repo-browser, etc), nothing happens.  No error message, no spinning-icon, nothing.  As if I didn't click anything.
2. When I click `START > ALL PROGRAMS > TORTOISE SVN > TortoiseSVN`, I get a popup error message `The ordinal 728 could not be located in the dynamic link library mfc90u.dll.`

The only change to my system that I did yesterday was to install Slik Subversion 1.6 in order to get the necessary 64 bit files to get Subclipse working on a 64 install of Eclipse.  I have since uninstalled Silk Subversion, but I am still getting the same error.

Thanks to anyone with ideas to help me.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Tortoise?

Comment: In an IT Crowd-esque voice: Have you tried turning it off and back again? I mean what @JasCav said.

Comment: Yes, I have uninstalled, rebooted, reinstalled, rebooted.  I have also installed the most recent version of Tortoise SVN.  All with absolutely no luck.  And I am installing the 64 bit version.